# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded when blending SKlearn Models

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to blend different models for SciKit learn so I can average their predictions.

This is `Ensemble` class that I've created:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin, RegressorMixin, clone

class AverageEnsembler(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin, TransformerMixin):
  def __init__(self, models):
    self.models = models

  def fit(self, X, y):
    self.models_ = [clone(x) for x in self.models]

    for mod in self.models_:
        mod.fit(X, y)


  def predict(self, X):
    predictions = np.column_stack([self.predict(X) for mod in self.models_])
    return np.mean(predictions, axis=1)
```

I've initialized the following models in this way:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
lasso = Lasso(alpha=.005, max_iter=5000)

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
ridge = Ridge(alpha=10)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, min_samples_leaf=5)

from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

gbr = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=3000, learning_rate=0.04, max_depth=3, 
max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=15, min_samples_split=10)
scores = np.sqrt(-1 * cross_val_score(estimator=gbr, X=X, y=y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', 
cv=10))
```

Anyways, anytime I try and call the `predict()` method I get this error.  I've tried different combinations of different models to pass into and it doesn't have an effect.  I never receive this error on any of the individual models when I fit them.

This is the traceback:

```
averaged_models = AverageEnsembler(models=[ridge, forest, xgb])
averaged_models.fit(X_linear, y)
averaged_models.predict(X_linear)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-341-1a5f198918ce> in <module>
----> 1 averaged_models.predict(X_linear)

<ipython-input-286-404e1a1b5a0a> in predict(self, X)
     14 
     15     def predict(self, X):
---> 16         predictions = np.column_stack([self.predict(X) for mod in self.models_])
     17         return np.mean(predictions, axis=1)

<ipython-input-286-404e1a1b5a0a> in <listcomp>(.0)
     14 
     15     def predict(self, X):
---> 16         predictions = np.column_stack([self.predict(X) for mod in self.models_])
     17         return np.mean(predictions, axis=1)

... last 2 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-286-404e1a1b5a0a> in predict(self, X)
     14 
     15     def predict(self, X):
---> 16         predictions = np.column_stack([self.predict(X) for mod in self.models_])
     17         return np.mean(predictions, axis=1)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you mean something like this:

```
class AverageEnsembler(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin, TransformerMixin):
  def __init__(self, models):
    self.models = models

  def fit(self, X, y):
    self.models_ = [clone(x) for x in self.models]

    for mod in self.models_:
        mod.fit(X, y)


  def predict(self, X):
    predictions = np.column_stack([mod.predict(X) for mod in self.models_])
    return np.mean(predictions, axis=1)
```

You are calling your own **predict** method in an infinite recursion.